# how to add this class using .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, squarespace

I have the following html code:

```
<nav id="main-navigation">    
<ul class="cf">

<li class=" active-link">
<a href="/">Home</a>
</li>

</ul>  
</nav>
```

I need to add the following code before the `</ul>` tag:

```
<li class="">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script> 
</li>
```

However, to do so, I have to use jquery's append(). But I don't know the correct way to add the `script type="text/javascript"`, `src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript">xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script>` inside the append().

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

So you can see what I'm trying to do:
what I need is the following http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/5/ The results are two links. However, the second link (the one which says "sacola de compras), must be done with append(), not html. That's what I'm trying to do

**EDIT 2:**

I tried the code in this Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/7/ and it works perfectly in Jsfiddle, but it does not work in my Squarespace website.

The code in my website is the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload=function(){ 
$('nav ul').append('<li id="hello"></li>');
$.getScript("https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118", function(){
    xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini","id=hello");
}); 
}
</script>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work in squarespace?

Thanks!

Comment: I think `$('nav ul').append('<li class=""><script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script><script type="text/javascript">xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script></li>');` should do it - jsfiddle seems to be messing it up

Comment: @ArunPJohny yeah, jsfiddle doesn't accept it, my website doesn't accept it either. It seems that this is not the correct way to add the html code inside the function

Comment: @user3507859 try what i suggested below in my answer. let me know if that works.

Comment: @AlexShilman thank you for helping! However, I can't seem to be able to create a separate html file because I'm working with Squarespace and there something I am not allowed to do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like

```
$.getScript("https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118", function(){
    xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini");
});
```

to load the script and then activate the xMinicart object afterwards? I can't really understand why you're trying to do this on the fly without more context so that's the best suggestion I can offer.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ (Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.)

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. But for you to understand, check my EDIT 1 in the original post, check out the jsfiddle in the edit. That's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to place it into that particular spot, then Try this: create a separate html file in the same directory, call it something like myli.html,
then you place this into it:

```
<ul id="myli">
  <li class="">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini"); </script> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your original page where you want this appended you do this, you have to create a dummy container like this

```
$('<div/>', {id:'dummycont', css: {display: 'none'}}).appendTo('body');
```

then

```
$('#dummycont').load('myli.html #myli, function(){
    var li = $(this).find('#myli').html();
    $('nav ul').prepend(li);
});
```

So basically this load event will load that particular #myli in the myli.html into a temp dummy container. Then you grab grab that content and prepend it to the target ul.
Let me know if that works for you. I havent tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are just appending the script as a Text or innerText in the HTML DOM structure.
Call the Js using the getScript or Ajax call. (Ajax call with return type script is a getScript)

And in its return function Call the xMinicart function.

In you Dom just Append a 'li' with a specific id and in the getScript success function pass the id to xMinicart function/

```
    <nav id="main-navigation">    
     <ul class="cf">

      <li class=" active-link">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="hello"></li>    
     </ul>

   </nav>
```

Your Js call should be

```
$.getScript("https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118", function(){
xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini","id=hello");
  });
```

This will load the cart on the page.

Check the Jsfiddle here   http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/6/

Comment: BTW you can append the <li id="hello"></li> through js and then call the getScript.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply! It works perfectly in jsfiddle but not in my Squarespace website. Do you have any idea why this happens? see the jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/u3NKD/7/ I'll also edit my original post with the Squarespace code so you can see it

Comment: Please add a link here. So that I can debug via console. Also try to debug it by giving a jquery ready function and putting a alert in the getscript success function. Atleast you will if the scripts actually get loaded.

Comment: this is the code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script>
window.onload=function(){ 
$('nav ul').append('<li id="hello"></li>');
$.getScript("https://app.ecwid.com/script.js?4549118", function(){
    xMinicart("style=","layout=Mini","id=hello");
}); 
}
</script>`